After converting a .py file to an .exe file console always closing
import yadisk
import os
from datetime import datetime

y = yadisk.YaDisk(token="TOKEN")

def run(path):
    date = datetime.strftime(datetime.now(), "%d.%m.%Y-%H.%M.%S")
    y.mkdir(f'/test/{date}')

    for address, dirs, files in os.walk(path):
        for dir in dirs:
            y.mkdir(f'/test/{date}/{dir}')
            print(f'Papka {dir} created')
        for file in files:
            print(f'File {file} downloaded')
            y.upload(f'{address}/{file}', f'/test/{date}/{file}')
    print("DONE")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    run(r'C:\Users\user.DESKTOP-IV3GN0E\Desktop')

If you run it in IDLE, the code works without problems and the files are uploaded to yandex.disk. And if you convert to .exe, then immediately after starting the console, the error "Traceback (most recent call last):
File"yadisk\client.py ", line 227"
How fix its?
I tried reinstalling the module, but it didn't help

can you post the rest of the traceback?

And there is nothing else. I have already written everything that is output to the console for a second

which operating system.  for example windows uses "/" or "\" in place of "" which is the escape character...
